# SymmetricDS: Can I call a stored procedure using initial.load.before.sql

Tags: oracle, symmetricds

I can get "initial.load.before.sql" in symmetric-server.properties to send a simple SQL statement to a receiving node.  But the [documentation](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.12/html/user-guide.html#_parameter_list) on what is allowed as a value for this parameter is pretty slim.

This works:

```
initial.load.before.sql=ALTER TABLE FOO.BAR disable CONSTRAINT BAR_PTY_FK
```

But what I would like to do is have SymmetricDS (SDS) execute a stored procedure on the receiving node prior to initial load that disables all the foreign key constraints (there are a lot).

I tried chaining a couple statements in "initial.load.before.sql". This works too:

```
initial.load.before.sql=ALTER TABLE FOO.BAR disable CONSTRAINT FOO_PTY_FK;ALTER TABLE FOO.BAR disable CONSTRAINT FOO_CTP_FK
```

But, if I include all the FK's I need, the "initial.load.before.sql" line will be pretty long.

I tried something like this:

```
initial.load.before.sql=FOO.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE()
```

But that value results in this error on the sending node:

> 2020-10-30 20:34:50,363 ERROR [sds-foo] [ManageIncomingBatchListener]
> [sds-foo-dataloader-2] Failed to load batch sds-master-1594
> StackTraceKey.init [SqlException:2002564836]
> org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Not sure if stored procedure are totally out or if I just need to keep tweaking the value I am providing for "initial.load.before.sql".  I experimented with different types of DML SQL statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) and those work well.  ALTER TABLE works fine too (as long as the SDS Oracle account has the required privileges).

If it helps w/ the answer, I am using Oracle and the SDS user db account on the receiving node has the required privileges to execute the store procedure. I can sucessfully execute the stored procedure as the SDS user (outside the scope the SDS software . . . . i.e. using a db client tool such as SQLDeveloper).  The version of SDS is 3.12.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a stored procedure, use a "call" statement, like this:

initial.load.before.sql=call FOO.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE()

If you are interested in deferring indexes, constraints, and foreign keys automatically during the initial load, take a look at parameters for auto.create=true and initial.load.defer.create.constraints=true.

Comment: Using a leading "CALL" worked, THANKS!  The tables I am loading already exist on the receiving node (not creating them at initial load or when using "symadmin -e blah reload-node client_id").  Calling a stored procedure with "initial.load.before.sql" lets me disable FK constraints so I can then use "truncate table %s" with "initial.load.delete.first.sql".  I then use "initial.load.after.sql" to re-enable the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try creating a stored function and call it using select statement like

select foo.bar() from dual;

?

This should work for Oracle

Comment: That would work if "bar()" was an Oracle function.  But since bar() is a stored procedure and not a function, I cannot call it that way.  If I change bar() to a function, "select foo.bar()" does not immediately throw an exception when I use it in "initial.load.before.sql".  Unfortunately, I am stuck with a stored procedure if I want to disable FK constraints in the receiving node.

Comment: Can you create a function that itself calls the stored procedure and returns something?